# Phonegap Facebook Connect Plugin NativeInterface Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, ripple

I get a TypeError in my try catch block on trying to do this with cordova and facebook connect plugin.

```
try {
      alert('Device is ready! Make sure you set your app_id below this alert.');
     FB.init({ appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
     }
      catch (e) {
              alert(e);
        }
```

On removing the "nativeInterface: CDV.FB", I get this error: missing exec:InAppBrowser.open

Why am I getting this error, or is there a walkaround for testing Phonegap app in Ripple Emulator? What I need to do is test the Facebook Connect plugin in Ripple before building in Phonegap Build.

On testing on the device I get a error: "TypeError does not have the method 'exec'" too and on trying to use the login I get :  "Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on login!Mut call init bfore login

Comment: Have you missed any of these? Create a keystore, You can use OpenSSL to get you hash key, Upload your keystore to PGB and rebuild your app. Update your FB app settings for native android with this hash key.

Comment: Oh!! are you trying to say that I can not use the Facebook Connect Plugin without a keystore, even for testing?

Comment: I have tried all this and generated release build of my app, but on the device I still get this error : "TypeError does not have the method 'exec'"

Comment: Review this "simple" example of the plugin you need to wait for deviceReady [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/example/Simple). "TypeError does not have the method 'exec'" - Its a known [issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/146)

Comment: It is working now when device ready is listened to, but my on my Facebook page I am getting : " The page you request cannot be display right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page." Any point @srk

Comment: That sounds like Fb server error, please try again and that should resolve.